# image in gridview

Tags: asp.net

HI

Im trying to show an image in a gridview, its held on the filesystem and the filename is returned in the datasource query.

If the files are held in C:\TEMP, how would I properly structure the code below?

thanks

```
<asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"C:\TEMP\" + Eval("ImagePath") %>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, your `ImageUrl` value needs to be relative to the root of your web application so if your webapp is in:

`c:\iis\MyWebApp`

and images are in:

`c:\iis\MyWebApp\img` the ImageUrl should evaluate to something like `~/img/Img1.jpg`

You could store the full path e.g. `~/img/Image1.jpg' in the db or just the filename, in which case you need to add the path to the ImageUrl value either in code-behind or in the markup.

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl.aspx) for more information.

Hth.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is along these lines

```
<asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl="C:\TEMP\<%= Eval("ImagePath") %>"/>
```